# mysqli does not work after installing mysqlnd on ubuntu

Tags: php, mysqli, ubuntu-14.04, mysqlnd

After installing php5-mysqlnd, php5-mysql is removed.
I install php5-mysql, php5-mysqlnd is removed and I can use mysqli. However, I will received this error

```
mysqli_real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50541 Library:50627
```

Based on other answers on stackoverflow, I need to install php5-mysqlnd to fix this. How to break out of this cycle?

UPDATE 1:

- Try to add extension = mysqlnd.so in php.ini
- try php5enmod mysqli and php5enmod mysqlnd in bash
- mysqli still does not work after installing php5-mysqlnd by apt-get

Comment: You cannot have both installed at once. [The PHP docs recommend you use mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1):

> mysqli_real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50541 Library:50627

The error message means that there is a version conflict on your system. You installed the package containing "libmysql" and the package "php5-mysql" which links against that library, while using a different version. This indicates that there either is a bug in packaging from Ubuntu (unlikely) or you messed up with different package sources. To be precise: PHP thinks it would use libmysql 5.5, whereas 5.6 is installed.

Anyways, to the other part of the question:  php5-mysqlnd and php5-mysql both contain the different MySQL userspace API libraries (mysql, mysqli and pdo_mysql) one package is the "traditional" one where those modules use libmysql, the other is the "modern" one where those modules use myslqnd. Documentation explaining the difference is on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php short form is: Use mysqlnd unless you have very specific requirements (i.e. using libmysld, with d in the end .. if you don't know what this is you don't want to use it; don't let it confuse you, use mysqlnd)

Now if there is no `mysqli` after installing `php5-mysqlnd` this might be caused by Ubuntu installing it, but not enabling the module, for this Ubuntu has a tool `php5enmod` try this:

```
php5enmod mysqli
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However, it does not work. Is there any other way? Or if there is any information I can give you to fix this bug?